# How to configure Apache to make him check the client certificate with the one in LDAP?

Tags: apache-2.2, ldap, certificate

I’m trying to configure my Apache server for an HTTPS authentication with client certificates using LDAP as my users directory.

What I want to do is that Apache asks users to authenticate themselves with a certificate (so without a login/password) and then Apache has to check it in the LDAP : if the certificate provided by the user is valid then Apache will return “it works” otherwise it will return a 401 authorization  required.

What I have done so far is : secure the connection between users and Apache and between Apache and LDAP. The user also provides his certificate to Apache when he tries to authenticate himself.
My problem is that the user provides a certificate to Apache but Apache doesn’t check if the certificate provided by the user match with the one associated to the user in the LDAP directory.

Here is my configuration file :

```
 < VirtualHost *:443>

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/conf/certs/apache.pem"
    SSLCertificateFile "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/conf/certs/apache.crt"
    SSLCACertificateFile "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/conf/certs/root.crt"
    SSLCACertificatePath "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/conf/certs/"
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv3 -SSLv2

    <Directory "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs">
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Authorized Personnel Only"
        AuthLDAPBindDN "cn=ldapadm,dc=ldap,dc=domain"
        AuthLDAPBindPassword "password"
        AuthBasicProvider ldap
        AuthLDAPURL "ldap://ldap.com/ou=People,dc=ldap,dc=domain?cn" STARTTLS
        AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
        Require valid-user

        SSLUserName SSL_CLIENT_CERT_S_DN_CN
        SSLRequire %{SSL_CLIENT_CERT_S_DN_CN} eq %{REMOTE_USER}
        SSLVerifyDepth 10
        SSLVerifyClient require
    </Directory>
< /VirtualHost>
```